# How to change the speed of speech in amazon polly (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I want to lower the speed at which the tts speaks at, I searched around for a couple of hours, but can't find the answer. Please help. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, here is an example for all of those who don't get it either.

```py
import boto3

polly_client = boto3.Session(
               aws_access_key_id='your_access_key_id',
               aws_secret_access_key='your_secret_access_key',
               region_name='your_region').client('polly')


response = polly_client.synthesize_speech(
               VoiceId='Joanna',
               OutputFormat='mp3',
               Engine = 'neural', 
               TextType = "ssml", 
               Text = "<speak><prosody rate='90%'>The Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over the Lazy Dog</prosody></speak>") # prosody rate changes the speed of the speech.

with open('folder/speech.mp3', 'wb') as file: #the folder part is here if you want to create the mp3 in a specific folder, if you don't want that, just remove it.
   file.write(response['AudioStream'].read())
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Voice Speed - Amazon Polly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/voice-speed-vip.html):

> Amazon Polly helps you slow down the rate of speech using the SSML  tag, as in:

```
<speak>
     In some cases, it might help your audience to <prosody rate="85%">slow 
     the speaking rate slightly to aid in comprehension.</prosody>
</speak>

or

<speak>
     In some cases, it might help your audience to <prosody rate="slow">slow 
     the speaking rate slightly to aid in comprehension.</prosody>
</speak>
```

Python can use the boto3 AWS SDK, which has a [`synthesize_speech()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/polly.html#Polly.Client.synthesize_speech) API call that accepts a `Text` field with the text to convert into speech. If you also set `TextType='ssml'`, then the text can include [SSML](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/ssml.html) as shown in the example above.

Comment: Btw, is there a way you can check how many words you have used with the tts this month or up till now, using python? Or, if that is not possible with python, is it available somewhere online?

Comment: @Bambi2k21 That would be related to billing, rather than the service itself. You _might_ be able to obtain information from the billing console or via billing API calls but I don't know how often it would be updated.

Comment: I see, huge thanks for responding, you usually get ignored around here when asking questions, so thanks for spending some of your time to help me.

Comment: Do you guys know to get the sound emotionally like question or exclamation?

Comment: @webmastx Are you wanting the voice to sound slightly different when asking a question or exclaiming something? It will automatically change the sound when a question mark is used. To emphasise something, use the SSML `<emphasis level="strong">` tag, but it doesn't sound that good (and doesn't work with a Neural Network voice). Take a look at the Polly documentation on SSML for examples.